# Is there an alternative to using Facebook credits in a payment service?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, facebook-credits, credits

Is there a way to implement a payment service in a Facebook app without the use of Facebook credits?

Comment: Policy questions are usually off-topic here - Facebook's payments terms are at https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a Facebook app in the narrow sense (an app that runs on facebook.com), then the answer is a definite no.

Outside of that, if you're referring to an app (on some other platform or website) that has some kind of Facebook integration, then you can use other payment systems there.